# Git - what should be in merge-commit after resolving conflicts

Tags: git, conflict, pull

I'm totally beginner in Git and I have a question.
For example, I have commited some changes in my local master branch. Before pushing it I'm doing a pull which produces conflict with one of files changed by me. After resolving this conflict I add the file to git index and make a merge commit. In my case in this merge commit I have all files modified in remote master branch , I my opinion it should be only the file which caused the conflict , which behavior is correct? When I do a pull without conflicts the merge commit contains any files.

Comment: Tip: normally you don't want to pull on top of your local changes, this leads to messy situations more often than not

Comment: So, could You explain, what is the best way to work with Git in this case?

Comment: Work in a different feature branches and pull on the develop or master branch, and then rebase your feature branch on top of that.

Comment: Ok thanks, And what in case of conflicts ? I resolve it and commit? It wouldn't produce the same problem I described?

Comment: You resolve but don't commit, rebase handles that for you, all you need to do is add the revised file and continue the rebase. It will certainly not produce the same problem

Comment: Thanks for Your response